# how to create a trigger when table transaction data is inserted that will reduce column quantity of table items

Tags: mysql

I am new to triggers but want to know how I can use one in my database. I have created a table for a transactions, and items. When transaction is carried out the items table should be affected like this,

1. if transaction_type "outgoing" is selected then trigger should
   reduce    the value of column 'quantity' in table items by the value
   in field quantity from table transaction.
2. if transaction_type "incoming" is selected then trigger should increase    the value of column 'quantity' in table items by the
   value in field quantity from table transaction.

here are the table

**1. table items**

```
`CREATE TABLE `items` (
 `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `purchase_date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `category_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `store_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `supplier_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `batch_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `quantity` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
 KEY `category` (`category_id`),
 KEY `store` (`store_id`),
 KEY `supplier` (`supplier_id`),
 KEY `batch` (`batch_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`
```

**2. table transactions**

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
 `transaction_id` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `transaction_date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `batch_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `store_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `transaction_type` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `remarks` longtext NOT NULL,
 `quantity` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_id`),
 KEY `item` (`item_id`),
 KEY `batch` (`batch_id`),
 KEY `store` (`store_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is what I have tried but when I run a transaction instead of reducing or adding the column quantity in table items it returns 0:

```
CREATE TRIGGER subtract_quantity AFTER INSERT ON transactions 
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE items 
SET items.quantity = items.quantity - transactions.quantity=transactions.quantity 
WHERE items.item_id = NEW.item_id
```

Comment: this is what i have tried but when i run a transaction instead of reducing or adding the column quantity in table items it returns 0                                     CREATE TRIGGER subtract_quantity AFTER INSERT ON transactions FOR EACH ROW UPDATE items SET items.quantity = items.quantity - transactions.quantity=transactions.quantity WHERE items.item_id = NEW.item_id

Comment: anyone to help me with this question?

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me

```html
CREATE TRIGGER `subtract_quantity` AFTER INSERT ON `transactions`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

      UPDATE items 

      SET items.quantity =  GREATEST(0, items.quantity - NEW.quantity)
      WHERE items.item_id = NEW.item_id
      and items.quantity > 0;
      
      UPDATE batches 
      SET batches.balance = GREATEST(0, batches.balance - NEW.quantity)
      WHERE batches.batch_id = NEW.batch_id
       and batches.balance > 0;
 END
```